# How to install kitkat 4.4.4 over Android 4.2.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

In my SONY Xperia Z current version of android version is 4.2.2. I want to remove this OS totally (as we remove windows OS to install newer) and install new Kitkat 4.4.4 version. I have followed this post at [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281), downloaded kitkat, but things are not working for me. Can anyone suggest me any solution of a brand new OS in my Android phone (my phone already rooted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give this toolkit a try it might might things a little easier for you http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z/development/tool-flashtool-v0-9-10-1-windows-linux-t2229790